# Silverlight rendering issue in Firefox 4 and 5 on MacBooks

Tags: silverlight, macos, plugins, rendering

We have encountered something that looks like a Silverlight 4 rendering problem when running our Silverlight 4 app in FireFox 4 and 5 on MacBook’s. There is no problem in Safari or OOB (that’s

Safari I guess).
The problem is that large parts of the UI goes white and gradually reappears by moving the mouse over the white areas, or if the UI canvas is repainted.

We use Telerik controls in our app, but the problem can occur just by scrolling a list inside a scrollviewer, so I dont think its Telerik related.

We have only seen this problem on MacBooks, not on iMacs.

Have anyone else experienced problems like this? Is this a problem in the Sl plugin?

See screenshots below.
I can provide a video if necessary.

Link to an example from our Silverlight client in FireFox 5 on a MacBook: [sl client on mac](http://partner.pageplannersolutions.com/images/ClientOk.png)

Link to an example of our client with the rendering issue: [sl client on mac with rendering issue](http://partner.pageplannersolutions.com/images/ClientRenderingProblems.png)

This question is also posted on Silverlight.net.

Comment: We "solved" this by disabling Hardware Acceleration explicitely for the mac clients. We haven't yet retested this with the latest SL5 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with either Firefox for mac, or the SL client. Try making sure you're running the most up-to-date versions of both (since it has been almost half a year since you've posted this, there are new versions).

Have you tried to reproduce your problem on a different browser? Does it happen on chrome or safari? If so, then it's probably a plugin issue.

I don't think you can write SL code that will cause the problem you are experiencing, so the fault is not likely with you.